# Detecting double tap on ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying detect if an item of ListView received double tap. To do it I created `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` and implemented all methods. But I can't know how I could get if item receive `onDoubleTap` or if item receive `onDown` action.

How could I know if item receive `onDoubleTap` or `onDown` ?

**Listener**

```
public class ListViewTouchListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();
        Log.d("Double Tap", "Tapped at: (" + x + "," + y + ")");

        return true;
    }
}
```

**ListView**

```
public class EntregaPendenteFrag extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
                                                             AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener,
                                                             AdapterView.OnTouchListener{
    //setOnTouchListener
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName() + "->";
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    //vendas entrega pendente
    private ListView lvEntregasPendente;
    private EntregaPendenteListAdapter entregaPendenteLA;
    private List<Venda> listaVenda;

    //itens venda
    private List<ItensVenda> listaItens;

    //dialog de parcelas
    public static AlertDialog alertDialogEntPendente;

    //touch item detector
    private GestureDetector gd;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entregas_pendente_frag, container, false);

        gd = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new ListViewTouchListener());

        lvEntregasPendente = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvEntregasPendente);
        lvEntregasPendente.setOnTouchListener(this);


        return  view;
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of a double tap listener here:
  https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Don't you need to continue calling super in the onTouchEvent?

```
@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

So in your code

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     gd.onTouchEvent(event);
      return super.onTouch( v, event );
}
```

Comment: He is using the same implementation using GestureDetector.